How to use a type predicate method to narrow the type of a private member?
I'm having trouble getting a working type predicate method to narrow the type of private bar? from string | undefined to string in class FooBad (adapted from this answer).  Classes FooGood1 and FooGood2 work around the issue by changing bar? from private to public or replacing hasBar() with an inline check of this.bar, respectively.
Is there a way to get FooBad to work by changing the type predicate of hasBar()?  I'd prefer to not use the workarounds; while FooGood2 would be acceptable for this minimal reproducible example, getting hasBar() to work with private bar? would be preferred for the actual code.

Not working (private bar?, hasBar() type predicate):
class FooBad {
  private bar?: string;

  private hasBar = (): this is { bar: string } => {
    return this.bar !== undefined;
  }

  printBar = () => {
    if (!this.hasBar()) { return; }

    /*
    Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'never'.
      The intersection 'this & { bar: string; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'bar' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some. ts(2339)
    */
    console.log(this.bar.toUpperCase());
  }
}


Workaround #1 (public bar?, hasBar() type predicate)
class FooGood1 {
  public bar?: string;

  private hasBar = (): this is { bar: string } => {
    return this.bar !== undefined;
  }

  printBar = () => {
    if (!this.hasBar()) { return; }
    console.log(this.bar.toUpperCase());
  }
}


Workaround #2 (private bar?, no hasBar() type predicate)
class FooGood2 {
  private bar?: string;

  printBar = () => {
    if (this.bar === undefined) { return; }
    console.log(this.bar.toUpperCase());
  }
}



Playground

See also microsoft/TypeScript#49709.

You can't do this without a workaround, sorry. See other linked q/a and ms/TS#49709
